# Parallax scrolling with custom scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, jquery-plugins

I am using parallax scrolling with the plugin (pixelcog parallax.js) its running fine with the default browser scroll bar but I am using custom scroll bar plugin on my website but parallax is not running. I tried the following code.

**Html:**

```
<body>
<section class="hobies-wrapper" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="images/parallax-img2.png"></section>
</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function myCustomFn(el){
    $('.hobies-wrapper').parallax({imageSrc: 'images/parallax-img2.png'});    
};
$(document).ready(function () 
{
$("body").mCustomScrollbar({
                theme:"minimal",
                mouseWheel:{ enable: true },
                keyboard:{ enable: true },
                mouseWheel:{ invert: true },
                documentTouchScroll: true,
                scrollEasing:"easeInOut",
                scrollButtons:{
                    enable:true
                    },
                callbacks:{
                    onScroll:function(){
                        myCustomFn(this);   
                    }
                    }
                    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**parallax.js** only detect Window scroll not any custom scrollBar.

parallax.js is not necessary. according to [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) try to create "parallax" scrolling effect by **CSS**

Comment: Yes that's very helpful.